# Local XML validation with DTD or XSD using a relative path?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation, xsd-validation, dtd

An XML file can be defined and validated with an Document Type Description (DTD) or  XML Schema (xsd) as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<annotation xmlns="http://www.xyz.com"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.xyz.com
    file:system.xsd" >
```

or

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE annotation SYSTEM "http://www.xyz.de/system.dtd">
```

Both ways define a URL where the DTD or XSD is found. Is there a way to give a relative or local path? So I can store them allong with the XML files instead of relying on a server?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's easy. Just put the relative location of the file like

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<annotation xmlns="http://www.xyz.com" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.xyz.com ./system.xsd" >
```

Comment: so why the url at all then?

Comment: Sometimes it may be necessary to write an xml that conforms to a schema that someone else produced. If they have it on a server then the tools can make sure they are always using the latest version of it.

Comment: I designed the xsd by myself, for now I would pass along the xsd with my xml files

Comment: That is what I am used to too.